# Bind de Collection com Spring 4 e Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Como faço para enviar uma lista quando o evento submit disparar no formulário?

O `Bind` do valor selecionado está sendo feito corretamente, mas eu  preciso da lista também.

HTML

```
<select id="banks" 
    th:field="*{bankID}" 
    class="form-control">
<option value="" 
    th:text="Selecione">
</option>
<option th:each="bank,rowStat : *{banks}"
    th:name="banks"
    th:value="${{bank.id}}" 
    th:text="${bank.name}">
</option>
```

Controller

```
public ModelAndView list(@Valid CheckSearchForm form, final BindingResult bindingResult)
```